# Average between dates with a simple query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to figure out how to figure out how to get the average of the difference of some dates I got on a table. I'm quite new to this, so I'm trying to get first the duration (as the difference between the dates) as a variable, and then call for the avg function, but this is a mess!!
This is what I'm currently trying to do, along with its consequently error message:

```
SQL> select months_between( select (finish_date from projects where id = 1), 
                            select ( start_date from projects where id = 1)
                          ) from dual;

    select months_between( select (finish_date from projects where id = 1),
                       *  ERROR at line 1: ORA-00936: missing expression
```

Can someone, please, point out for me where the missing expression is?? I think all the columns are typed in.

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: Sorry, You put multiple SQLs as One ??

Comment: I just fixed that with that query:                                SQL> select ((select finish_date from projects where id = 1) - (select start_date from projects
  2  where id = 1)) from dual;

((SELECTFINISH_DATEFROMPROJECTSWHEREID=1)-(SELECTSTART_DATEFROMPROJECTSWHEREID=1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                             581

Comment: please remove mysql tag, I don't think its relevant here

Comment: You've fixed the error you asked about, which is good. You're only looking at values for one row; do you want the average difference over all rows? And as what, the number of days?

Comment: You can't structure the query like that - you have parenthesis out of place.  There's a couple of different ways to structure this... as before, sample starting data and desired results

Answer (score 0):

It's really tough to work out precisely what you are asking, but working on the presumption that you want the average number of months between the start and end date of all projects, you basically want this:

```
SELECT AVG( MONTHS_BETWEEN( start_date, finish_date ) )
FROM   projects
```

Basically you "MONTH_BETWEEN" will work out the difference between the dates for each row the SELECT statement finds, and then the AVG will group them all up into a single row and work out the average (mean) for you.

You can see what the MONTHS_BETWEEN does if you just take the AVG off and try the following:

```
SELECT start_date, finish_date, MONTHS_BETWEEN( start_date, finish_date )
FROM   projects
```

If you want the average from a smaller subset, then you can add a where clause.

E.g. for projects started after 01-01-2014:

```
SELECT AVG( MONTHS_BETWEEN( start_date, finish_date ) )
FROM   projects
WHERE  start_date > TO_DATE( '01-01-2014', 'dd-mm-yyyy' )
```

Or let's say you wanted the average for each department's project (if that is in your data model), you would add the department to the SELECT and add a GROUP BY:

```
SELECT department, AVG( MONTHS_BETWEEN( start_date, finish_date ) )
FROM   projects
GROUP BY department
```

Does that answer your question?